# TLS 1.0 in the middle

Tags: ssl, tls1.2, tls1.0

So I have 2 services in my network which are both setup to run with TLS 1.2 as minimum standard.

They communicate via a proxy network device which has the minimum TLS version set to 1.0.

Now am I correct to assume that all communication via the network device will happen only with TLS 1.2?

Comment: 1.2 is the lowest possible version that could be used. The peers negotiate the highest version that both support. Since you have not specified what the **maximum** version each protocol stack supports there's no way to know whether they would use 1.2, 1.3(available now), or some higher version (at some point in the future).

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Thanks for clarifying that. Yes my concern really is if it would use TLS 1.2 as the minimum and it wouldn't use TLS 1.0/1.1 at all.